# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning Issues with scanfilter

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

When i try to use ScanFilter in BleScan in lollipop its not scanning devices(Only when i pass List of ScanFilter). If i pass only one UUID its working fine. But in the case of Multiple its not working..

```
 ScanSettings settings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED).build();
        if (getBluetoothStatus()) {
            mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
            List<ScanFilter> mList=scanFilters(serviceUUIDs);
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(mList, settings, mScanCallback);

        }



     private List<ScanFilter> scanFilters(UUID[] serviceUUIDs) {
                List<ScanFilter> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i <serviceUUIDs.length; i++) {
                ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(serviceUUIDs[0].toString())).build();

                    list.add(filter);
                }

          return list;
            }
```

Comment: try this: ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(serviceUUIDs[i].toString())).build();

Comment: please accept as it an asnwer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

that's beacause you don't use the variable to go trough on elements.

try this:

```
ScanFilter filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(serviceUUIDs[i].toStri‌​ng())).build();
```